# string.indexOf is not workign for some characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to block some words that I have set file, but it never return true for worlds with č,ř,é,í,á,ř,ť. I don't know if it's problem with decoding my json file or problem of string.indexOf

```
var content = data;
let json3 = JSON.parse(content)['badwords'];
length = json3.length;
while(length--) {
  if (msg.indexOf(json3[length])!=-1) {
     console.log('yes');
     return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is with JSON - maybe you set such encoding in JSON file which does not support characters č,ř,é,í,á,ř,ť. Try to save JSON file in utf-8 encoding.